# Bad operand type for unary in python

Tags: python, tkinter

I am getting trouble making a program to calculate the quadratic formula in python. I am new to this and I figured it would be a good idea to learn how to make a window and some button. The error I am getting is :

> File "quadratic.py", line 9, in quadratic
>      sol1 = (-(b) - (math.sqrt((b**2) - (4*a*c)))/(2*a))
>   TypeError: bad operand type for unary -: 'str'

I have tried to play around with parenthesis but that doesn't seem to be the problem.

```
from tkinter import *
import math

def quadratic():
   a = entrya.get()
   b = entryb.get()
   c = entryc.get()

   sol1 = (-(b) - (math.sqrt((b**2) - (4*a*c)))/(2*a))
   sol2 = (-(b) + (math.sqrt((b**2) - (4*a*c)))/(2*a))

   textd = Label(my_window, text="The solutions are {0} and {1}".format(sol1,sol2)) 


my_window = Tk()

texta = Label(my_window, text="Enter a:")
entrya = Entry(my_window)

textb = Label(my_window, text="Enter b:")
entryb = Entry(my_window)

textc = Label(my_window, text="Enter c:")
entryc = Entry(my_window)

button1 = Button(my_window, text="Calculate", command = quadratic)  

texta.pack()
entrya.pack()
textb.pack()
entryb.pack()
textc.pack()
entryc.pack()
button1.pack()

my_window.mainloop()
```

Comment: The error says it all... The values you `.get()` are strings, not numbers.

Comment: You are trying to use the unary negation, I e. `-` (the negative sign) on a string object, but string objects don't support that. Try converting to a numeric datatype, like `float`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change say `a = entrya.get()` to `a = float(entrya.get())` and so on.

```
def quadratic():
   a = float(entrya.get())
   b = float(entryb.get())
   c = float(entryc.get())

   sol1 = (-(b) - (math.sqrt((b**2) - (4*a*c)))/(2*a))
   sol2 = (-(b) + (math.sqrt((b**2) - (4*a*c)))/(2*a))

   textd = Label(my_window, text="The solutions are {0} and {1}".format(sol1,sol2))
```